# Does a loop reset every time you  go through it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
 cout << " 1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9" << endl << "" << endl;
 for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++) {
   cout << c << "| ";
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     cout << i * c << '\t';
   }
   cout << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Hey so this code produces a times table...I found it on Google Code's C++ class online...I'm confused about why "i" in the second for loop resets to 1 every time you go through that loop...or is it being declared again in the first parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jon - you're right.  It contains two.

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow. (please don't repost it there - it will be migrated automatically if eonugh people agree with this and vote to close it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It "reverts" to 1 because you explicitly set it to 1 as the start condition of the loop...

The "i" name does not exist outside this loop, so each time this loop is run (for each iteration of 'c'), then "i" is a new variable, set to a start of 1.

Comment: Ok Thanks...that's kind of what I assumed but this website is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

As TZHX has written. FOR statements usually have three clauses that are in the parantheses (technically they always have three but you don't have to specify them), and a statement that is repeated (often a statement block).

Of those three clauses, the first is an initializer, the second controls the looping, and the third is the increment. So as TZHX says, i is reset to 1 at the beginning due to the initializer clause. This will keep repeating while i<10 (the second clause), and i is incremented by 1 with each iteration (the third clause).